# How do I remove all duplicates in one column, and keep the row with highest value (from another column)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to remove duplicate CustomerIDs and keep the one with the highest CompositeRank.

```
CUSTOMERID     STORE      COMPOSITERANK
51872          FOS        5
51872          MOS        3
51872          BOS        2
10098          BOS        5
10098          MOS        3
10098          FOS        2
99102          MOS        5
99102          FOS        3
99102          BOS        2
```

After removing the proper duplicates, it should look like this:

```
CUSTOMERID     STORE      COMPOSITERANK
51872          FOS        5
10098          BOS        5
99102          MOS        5
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi step approach:

1. Sort by customerID then compositerank Desc
2. Add a formula similar to the following `=IF(A2=A1,0,1)` 3)
3. add a filter for 1  achieve results similar to below screenshot.

[image]

If you need to retain ordering first add a column with 1 and then 1 + row above and fill the series down.  Then after step 3, re-order based on column added.

you can then copy /paste results to different worksheet if needed, or just leave the non-highest ones hidden.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Took me a second to figure out why it works haha.

Comment: Guess I could have explained it a little better.  This works because each customer is grouped together with the highest compositeRank in the row of each customer group.  When the customers change, then we know that row will have the highest composite rank, and thus we set that value to 1 and all others to 0.  When we filter by 1 we get all the desired records.  (for others benefit if they don't understand why)